# Loop over a list of wrapper class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I am new to javascript.
I have a list of wrapper class and want to loop over that structure and get the value out of that in javascript.

```
[
    employeeBookedClass:[
        locationDate=19/02/2018, 
        locationName=London, 
        trainerName=Nayank, 
        uniqueId=19/02/2018~London
    ], 
    employeeBookedClass:[
        locationDate=12/03/2018, 
        locationName=Rajasthan, 
        trainerName=Chris, 
        uniqueId=12/03/2018~Rajasthan
    ]
]
```

this is my structure. How can I iterate over it.

Comment: That does not look like javascript.... and you can find many examples about how to loop using for or something else on Google, so is there any deeper problem?

Comment: This is what I get when I print a list<someClass> in javascript. I want to loop over the this is list in javascript

Comment: There is no `list<someClass>` in Javascript. Are you sure that you are not mixing up Java and Javascript?

Comment: _This looks like Python, doesn't it_ ? Whatever the language, you might have to turn your Iterable into a JSON string, dump this into your Javascript context (HTML page?). Then you should be ready to try out some Javascript code with your newly flushed data. If you still struggle, please add your code snippets trials to the question content as an edit.